# Google Cloud Firestore: How to copy Firestore collection to Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-firestore

Writing a code is the only option to copy Firestore collections to Cloud Storage or is there some kind of a magic feature I can use?

I know this new feature announcement of importing Firestore collection into BigQuery in the Firestore talk during the Next conference. Is there something similar for Cloud Storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/export-import. Not so sure whether this is a new feature but I am going to try this out.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, finally, Firebase enabled this feature.**

1. [Create Cloud Storage Bucket](https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/)
2. install gcloud if not already: in terminal run `curl
   https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash`

   - after prompt `Modify profile to update your $PATH and enable bash completion? (Y/n)` type `y` + enter
3. next, run `source .bash_profile`
4. afterwards, run: `gcloud beta firestore export gs://[BUCKET-NAME]`.

---

5. and in case, you want to save the folder locally, simply run `gsutil cp -r gs://[BUCKET-NAME] /path/to/folder`